# How to change Load Balancer of Elastic Beanstack environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to have multiple Elastic Beanstalk environments sharing a single Application Load Balancer. I took this idea from the following article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-application-load-balancer-unlocking-and-optimizing-architectures/.

Following the steps described in there I was able to create a dedicated Application Load Balancer and forward the traffic to different microservices depending on the request path. Sadly in my setup I'm still stuck with the original load balancers created by Elastic Beanstack for each environment. So even though it works great I have to have N + 1 load balancers, N being a number of microservices - Elastic Beanstack environments. This ends up quite ineffective, as the load balancers created by EB just sit there and do nothing. Each of them still costs around $15/monthly.

In ideal world I could specify the ALB to use in `.ebextenstions` but I know this is not the case. I'm looking for a way to update the Load Balancer used by EB environment, to be able to delete the ALB created with each EB environment.

So when I run:

```
# aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-id e-skkhtau5sm 
{
    "EnvironmentResources": {
        "Triggers": [],
        "Queues": [],
        "AutoScalingGroups": [
            {
                "Name": "awseb-e-skkhtau5sm-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-PLMP93QLTO0N"
            }
        ],
        "LaunchConfigurations": [
            {
                "Name": "awseb-e-skkhtau5sm-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-TKO2UHT9YFF"
            }
        ],
        "EnvironmentName": "sg-trading-alb",
        "Instances": [
            {
                "Id": "i-067b3a3454dd68fd2"
            }
        ],
        "LoadBalancers": [
            {
                "Name": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:974556904237:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-LR8CLD9OP42A/8916dc615a011726"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to change a value in `EnvironmentResources.LoadBalancers[0].Name`. Has anyone succeeded in doing such change ?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is designed for easy deployment of single applications. If you want something more complex, it's time to move to CloudFormation.

Comment: Well, I know I can do anything in CloudFormation but if I migrate my environments to this level  I will have to spend hundreds of hours of developemnt to have  everything Beanstalk does out of the box - rolling deployment, versioning, log management, etc. That's too low level.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question, I solved my problem by migrating out of Elastic Beanstack and using ECS directly instead. For deployment I used `ecs-deploy` script. I recommend this path.